# what is an good way to define a bounded plane to make line intersections easy?

Tags: math, definition, line-intersection

I want to define a bounded plane, ie a rectangle in 3d space. I realize it could be defined just by declaring its 4 vertices, but I will be using a line intersection algorithm many times on this shape so I want the definition to be somewhat useful for that purpose. Is there some standard way to define something like this?

Answer (score 2):

It is worth to define one corner as base point, and two perpendicular vectors for neighbor sides.

For example **A**, **V**=**AB**, **U**=**AD**. In this case

```
B = A + V
D = A + U
C = A + U + V
N = V x U   (normal to the plane is cross product of vectors)
```

Any point belonging to the plane has equation

**P** = **A** + v * **V** + u * **U**

And both coefficients `v` and `u` are in range `0..1` for points **inside** bounds